# Error creating a 2D array from a structure

Tags: c#, struct

I've been trying to create a structure and later use that structure to create a 2D array but I keep getting an error about the type ( cannot convert type 'int' to Point). Here's my code:

```
public struct Point
{
    public int x, y;
};

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Point[,] points = { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 0, 2 } };
}
```

Any ideas how I could solve this problem? I'm relatively new to programming and would need some guidance :)

Comment: Note that you are trying to create a 2D array of `Point`, not of `int`, yet you are specifying `int`s as your array items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to create good old **1D** array of `Point`:

```
Point[] points = new Point[] {
  new Point() {x = 0, y = 0 },
  new Point() {x = 1, y = 0 }, 
  new Point() {x = 2, y = 1 }, 
  new Point() {x = 1, y = 2 }, 
  new Point() {x = 0, y = 2 },
};
```

If you don't want to be that *wordy* you can modify `Point` a bit:

```
public struct Point {
  public Point(int x, int y) {
    X = x;
    Y = y;    
  }

  //DONE: Exposing fields is a bad practice; converted to property
  //DONE: struct are often immutable (private set) 
  public int X {get; private set;}
  public int Y {get; private set;}
}
```

Then you can do

```
Point[] points = new Point[] {
  new Point(0, 0),
  new Point(1, 0), 
  new Point(2, 1), 
  new Point(1, 2), 
  new Point(0, 2),
};
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thanks :)